# R: is there a way to cbind non-numeric columns

Tags: r, precision, numeric, cbind

```
library(Rmpfr)
mynumber <- new("mpfr", .Data = list(new("mpfr1", prec = 50L, exp = c(1045L, 
0L), sign = 1L, d = c(151748608L, -358118319L)), new("mpfr1", 
    prec = 50L, exp = c(20L, 0L), sign = 1L, d = c(-1114947584L, 
    -1905679017L)), new("mpfr1", prec = 50L, exp = c(-55L, -1L
), sign = 1L, d = c(-1449918464L, -906197701L)), new("mpfr1", 
    prec = 50L, exp = c(221L, 0L), sign = 1L, d = c(819707904L, 
    -1329031570L))))
```

`mynumber` is a class `mpfr` object with 4 numbers in it. I want to `cbind` `mynumber` with a column of 0s, i.e.

```
> cbind(rep(0, 4), mynumber)
       mynumber
[1,] 0 ?       
[2,] 0 ?       
[3,] 0 ?       
[4,] 0 ?
```

This gives me ???? in the second column, so I tried to change `mynumber` to class `numeric` first

```
mydata <- cbind(rep(0, 4), sapply(mynumber, asNumeric))
> mydata
     [,1]         [,2]
[1,]    0          Inf
[2,]    0 5.833223e+05
[3,]    0 2.189941e-17
[4,]    0 2.327185e+66
```

However, since the first number in `mynumber` is really big, using asNumeric changed it into `Inf` instead.

Edit:
My ultimate goal is to run:

```
mydata <- cbind(rep(0, 4), sapply(mynumber, asNumeric))
> mydata/rowSums(mydata)
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0  NaN
[2,]    0    1
[3,]    0    1
[4,]    0    1
```

and not have it print out NaN.

Comment: `mynumber` results from my calling the function `mpfr` from `Rmpfr`. Is there any additional information on packages that I should provide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to wrap with `list` and then create a `tibble/data.frame` object as `cbind` converts to a `matrix` and `matrix` can hold only a single class

```
library(tibble)
tibble(col1 = 0, col2 = list(mynumber))
# A tibble: 1 x 2
#   col1 col2  
#  <dbl> <list>
#1     0 <mpfr>
```

---

`cbind` on even a `character` and `numeric` class returns `character` for all the columns and this is not a good option when the `vector`s to bind are of different class

```
cbind(letters[1:4], 1:4)
```

---

By checking the `methods` for `cbind` after loading the package

```
methods('cbind')
#[1] cbind,ANY-method     cbind,Mnumber-method cbind.bigq*          cbind.bigz*         
#[5] cbind.data.frame     cbind.grouped_df*    cbind.ts*
```

So, if it was using the correct `cbind` methods for `Mnumber`, it should not have given `Inf`

```
cbind(rep(0,4),  mynumber)
#'mpfrMatrix' of dim(.) =  (4, 2) of precision  50 .. 53  bits 
#     [,1] [,2]                   
#[1,]   0. 3.4556867084990952e+314
#[2,]   0.      583322.33392099757
#[3,]   0.  2.1899410233914937e-17
#[4,]   0.  2.3271850367397449e+66
```

Or make use of the recycling of value

```
cbind(0,  mynumber)
#'mpfrMatrix' of dim(.) =  (4, 2) of precision  50 .. 53  bits 
#     [,1] [,2]                   
#[1,]   0. 3.4556867084990952e+314
#[2,]   0.      583322.33392099757
#[3,]   0.  2.1899410233914937e-17
#[4,]   0.  2.3271850367397449e+66
```

---

Also, if we check the masked the functions, when we load the package, it says

> The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:
>
> cbind, pmax, pmin, rbind

By using the `cbind` from `base`, the `?` can be replicated.  It is possible that for the OP, the `cbind` is from `base`

```
base::cbind(0, mynumber)
#       mynumber
#[1,] 0 ?       
#[2,] 0 ?       
#[3,] 0 ?       
#[4,] 0 ?
```

If the `cbind` from `Rmpfr` got masked, then use `::`

```
mydata <- Rmpfr::cbind(0, mynumber)
mydata
#'mpfrMatrix' of dim(.) =  (4, 2) of precision  50 .. 53  bits 
#     [,1] [,2]                   
#[1,]   0. 3.4556867084990952e+314
#[2,]   0.      583322.33392099757
#[3,]   0.  2.1899410233914937e-17
#[4,]   0.  2.3271850367397449e+66




mydata/rowSums(mydata)
#'mpfrMatrix' of dim(.) =  (4, 2) of precision  53   bits 
#     [,1] [,2]              
#[1,]   0. 1.0000000000000000
#[2,]   0. 1.0000000000000000
#[3,]   0. 1.0000000000000000
#[4,]   0. 1.0000000000000000
```

Comment: Thank you.  I have a follow up question, suppose I had `mydata <- cbind(rep(0, 4), sapply(mynumber, asNumeric))`. And when I call `mydata/rowSums(mydata)`, it gives me an `NaN`. Is there a way to use `tibble` to get around this? I edited my original question.

Comment: Let's go with `mydata <- cbind(seq(1, 4, 1), sapply(mynumber, asNumeric))` then.

Comment: Thanks. How can I make sure to use the `cbind` method for `Mnumber`?

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if there is something wrong with your created object. When I changed it to make sure each `exp` field only had a single value, I got the desired result:

```r
library(Rmpfr)

x <- new("mpfr", .Data = list(new("mpfr1", prec = 50L, exp = 1045L, 
    sign = 1L, d = c(151748608L, -358118319L)), new("mpfr1", 
    prec = 50L, exp = 20L, sign = 1L, d = c(-1114947584L, -1905679017L
    )), new("mpfr1", prec = 50L, exp = -55L, sign = 1L, d = c(-1449918464L, 
-906197701L)), new("mpfr1", prec = 50L, exp = 221L, sign = 1L, 
    d = c(819707904L, -1329031570L))))

cbind(c(0, 0, 0, 0), x)
#> 'mpfrMatrix' of dim(.) =  (4, 2) of precision  50 .. 53  bits 
#>      [,1] [,2]                   
#> [1,]   0. 3.4556867084990952e+314
#> [2,]   0.      583322.33392099757
#> [3,]   0.  2.1899410233914937e-17
#> [4,]   0.  2.3271850367397449e+66
```

<sup>Created on 2020-02-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: When I tried to run `x <- new(....)` I got the following error: `Error in validObject(.Object) : 
  invalid class “mpfr1” object: invalid 'exp' slot for 64-bit gmp.numbbits: must have length 2`. Not sure what this means?

Comment: @Adrian I'm guessing it's because I'm on a 32-bit architecture and you're on 64-bit. I suspect this is an issue with the version of `cbind` being called as @akrun says

Answer (score 0):

```
zeros <- mpfr(c(0,0,0,0), precBits = getPrec(mynumber))
M <- cbind(mynumber, zeros)
M %*% t(M) # just to try
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the following error: `Error in base::"%*%"(x, y) : 
  requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments`. Am I suppose to be using the `%*%` operator from anoter package?

Comment: @Adrian Strange. I just loaded `Rmpfr`, which provides this operator.